# PineScript - Adding Input to ON/OFF chart plots

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v4

New to PineScript.

I added this indicators script(https://www.tradingview.com/script/a0vTLaS6-Double-Top-Bottom-Ultimate-OS/) to my original strategy, so I can add new conditions for strategy.close/entry, but the problem is that my previous chart plots and some buttons now are not working anymore. I think that the new script that I inserted (copy/past) is overlaying the previous strategy, thus the previous chart plots are not working. In this case, I think the best option is to create an Input.bool for the boxes shown below.

[image]

I came up with this:

xyz = input(title="XYZ", type=input.bool, defval=false)

But I don't know how I should relate this input to its relevant line. I think line 172 is the relevant code for this boxes:

```
labelText = (doubleTop? "Double Top" : "Double Bottom") + (DisplayRiskPerReward ? " RR - "+tostring(riskPerReward) : "")
```

Also, In case I want to add(copy/past) new scripts to my strategy. Is there a way to
create a button for the whole indicator, within my indicator? For instance, my indicator's name is "XYZ" and I want to add "ABC" inside "XYZ". Is there a way to set a button for "ABC", so when I use the general indicator ("XYZ"), I can just turn it off and on? Is it normal input? or I should indent everything in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you want to have an input to enable/disable that "Double Bottom RR" label, you can have an input variable for that and use an if condition to decide if you should plot or not.

Create an input:
bool plotLabel = input(true)

Then modify line 172, where plotting is handled as below (note the indentation):

```
var  label baseLabel = na

if (plotLabel == true)
    labelText = (doubleTop? "Double Top" : "Double Bottom") + (DisplayRiskPerReward ? " RR - "+tostring(riskPerReward) : "")

    baseLabel := label.new(x=index, y=value, text=labelText, yloc=doubleTop?yloc.abovebar:yloc.belowbar,
      color=doubleTop?bearishColor:bullishColor, 
      style=doubleTop?label.style_label_down:label.style_label_up,
      textcolor=textColor, size=size.normal)
```

So in order to plot that label, plotLabel input must be `true`.

> Also, In case I want to add(copy/past) new scripts to my strategy. Is
> there a way to create a button for the whole indicator, within my
> indicator? For instance, my indicator's name is "XYZ" and I want to
> add "ABC" inside "XYZ". Is there a way to set a button for "ABC", so
> when I use the general indicator ("XYZ"), I can just turn it off and
> on? Is it normal input? or I should indent everything in the code?

No, you need to modify the code and add enable/disable input for the whole script that you copy.

Comment: Your answer is in V5 or V4 ? (Im using V4) because I got a bunch of "Undeclared Identifier" errors. example : Undeclared Identifier ' plotLable'

Comment: It's in v4. Did you copy my code or write it yourself? Because it looks like you have a typo. It is not `plotLable` in my example. It is `plotLabel`. Also, please pay attention to the indentation in if block.

Comment: There was an indentation problem. It worked! Thanks!

Comment: "No, you need to modify the code and add enable/disable input for the whole script that you copy." can you tell me how I can set up a input.bool argument for this indicator?

Comment: It's in my answer: `bool plotLabel = input(true)`